# mongodb: can't get query executor when executing geoNear aggregate

Tags: mongodb

when executing the following aggregate

```
db.Activities.aggregate([
   {
     $geoNear: {
        near: { coordinates: [ -73.99279 , 40.719296 ] },
        distanceField: "location.calculated",
        spherical: true,
     }
   }
])
```

I am getting the following error

```
uncaught exception: aggregate failed: {
    "errmsg" : "exception: geoNear command failed: { ok: 0.0, errmsg: \"can't get query executor\" }",
    "code" : 16604,
    "ok" : 0
}
```

when i run the geoNear command, it works fine.

```
db.runCommand( {
   geoNear: "Activities" ,
   near: [ -73.99279 , 40.719296 ],
   spherical: true,
})
```

Any ideas what i am doing worng ?

Answer (score 3):

The problems could be:

1. You are missing a "2dsphere" index in collection `Activities`.
2. There are multiple geo indexes in collection `Activities`

Run this code in Mongo shell to see all the indexes

```
db.Activities.getIndexes()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found a solution which was not obvious.

Here's the index:

```
db.buildings.createIndex(
    {    
        'Address.CityCode': 1,
        'Rooms.Categories': 1,
        'Address.Coords': '2dsphere'
    },
    {
        background: true,
        name: 'IX_Address.CityCode_Rooms.Category_Address.Coords_Published',
        partialFilterExpression: { 'Rooms.Published': true }
    }
);
```

So i was getting that *"can't get query executor"* because of 2 things:

- As it's seen the index is compound, and as it's told [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-16592) your *query* must contain all the fields from index
- Secondly, after experimenting with index options it turned out that '*partialFilterExpression*' causes same error as well..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a compound index, a 2sphere and another type of index, something like:

```
{
    "name: 1,
    "location" : "2dsphere"
}
```